# How do I convert my .svg to a woff icon font?

Tags: fonts, svg, icon, file-conversion

I have tried all conversion websites and softwares but I cannot seem to get my .svg to convert to a .woff file (or any font file ex. eot .ttf ) so I can add it as an icon to my website. I know very little about coding, so it could be an easy fix and I just can't see it. This is the code for the .svg in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 20.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 150 150" style="enable-background:new 0 0 150 150;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <path style="fill:#5E5F5F;" d="M121.27,58.378c-0.347-1.07-0.705-2.176-1.059-3.519c-0.173-0.657-0.767-1.116-1.447-1.118
        l-75.521-0.197c-0.571-0.012-1.046,0.292-1.313,0.767c-1.24,2.212-2.995,4.862-4.853,7.667
        c-5.018,7.575-10.207,15.407-9.824,20.751c0.017,0.22,0.018,0.439,0.02,0.656c0.008,0.853,0.018,1.913,0.712,2.903
        c0.819,1.176,2.25,1.946,3.739,2.012c1.766,0.071,3.845,0.049,5.238,0.019c0.002,4.56,0.367,16.74,4.083,20.455
        c3.377,3.383,8.173,4.14,16.173,4.176v14.029c0,0.828,0.671,1.5,1.5,1.5h44.671c0.829,0,1.5-0.672,1.5-1.5v-24.885
        c11.622-7.215,17.469-18.708,17.868-35.105C122.85,63.252,122.117,60.994,121.27,58.378z M102.626,99.96
        c-0.456,0.271-0.735,0.761-0.735,1.29v24.229H60.22v-14.03c0-0.399-0.159-0.782-0.442-1.063c-0.281-0.279-0.661-0.437-1.058-0.437
        c-0.002,0-0.005,0-0.008,0c-9.356,0.067-12.972-0.72-15.543-3.295c-2.591-2.591-3.332-13.547-3.19-19.845
        c0.009-0.414-0.152-0.813-0.447-1.103c-0.294-0.291-0.705-0.453-1.109-0.431c-0.038,0.001-3.789,0.142-6.571,0.026
        c-0.562-0.024-1.113-0.311-1.407-0.732c-0.155-0.221-0.166-0.604-0.171-1.212c-0.003-0.281-0.006-0.566-0.027-0.848
        c-0.31-4.32,5.037-12.391,9.333-18.875c1.684-2.542,3.285-4.958,4.529-7.088l73.511,0.191c0.275,0.951,0.548,1.795,0.798,2.564
        c0.825,2.547,1.422,4.388,1.343,7.613C119.38,82.539,113.775,93.348,102.626,99.96z"/>

<path style="fill:#5E5F5F;" d="M70.907,30.59l1.544,0.198c0.152,0.628,0.393,1.205,0.731,1.748l-0.948,1.247
        c-0.081,0.106-0.115,0.239-0.098,0.37c0.018,0.132,0.087,0.25,0.193,0.331l2.646,2.01c0.216,0.165,0.526,0.125,0.695-0.089
        l1.002-1.275c0.567,0.195,1.128,0.334,1.963,0.242l0.592,1.409C79.28,36.903,79.377,37,79.5,37.05
        c0.061,0.025,0.125,0.037,0.189,0.037c0.066,0,0.132-0.013,0.194-0.039l3.064-1.288c0.254-0.107,0.374-0.4,0.267-0.655
        l-0.592-1.409c0.645-0.526,0.938-1.021,1.201-1.571l1.613,0.176c0.267,0.027,0.516-0.164,0.55-0.435l0.416-3.297
        c0.017-0.131-0.02-0.264-0.101-0.369c-0.082-0.105-0.201-0.173-0.333-0.189l-1.554-0.195c-0.152-0.621-0.395-1.197-0.737-1.745
        l0.939-1.243c0.08-0.106,0.115-0.239,0.096-0.371c-0.019-0.132-0.088-0.25-0.194-0.33l-2.662-2.003
        c-0.221-0.166-0.53-0.123-0.696,0.094l-0.973,1.258c-0.566-0.193-1.125-0.333-1.959-0.241l-0.593-1.41
        c-0.107-0.255-0.401-0.374-0.655-0.267l-3.064,1.288c-0.122,0.051-0.219,0.149-0.269,0.272s-0.049,0.26,0.002,0.383l0.593,1.409
        c-0.645,0.527-0.938,1.022-1.199,1.568l-1.581-0.186c-0.274-0.036-0.519,0.16-0.554,0.432l-0.432,3.304
        c-0.018,0.132,0.019,0.265,0.1,0.37S70.775,30.573,70.907,30.59z M71.834,27.345l1.45,0.17c0.213,0.026,0.433-0.114,0.523-0.311
        c0.317-0.692,0.526-1.149,1.333-1.722c0.191-0.135,0.263-0.385,0.172-0.602l-0.549-1.306l2.143-0.9l0.549,1.306
        c0.091,0.217,0.323,0.342,0.55,0.298c0.972-0.177,1.446-0.005,2.187,0.261c0.203,0.072,0.432,0.007,0.564-0.165l0.893-1.154
        l1.867,1.405l-0.85,1.125c-0.131,0.173-0.135,0.412-0.01,0.589c0.438,0.622,0.717,1.282,0.852,2.018
        c0.039,0.214,0.213,0.379,0.429,0.406l1.411,0.177l-0.292,2.313l-1.48-0.162c-0.22-0.021-0.432,0.122-0.522,0.317
        c-0.317,0.69-0.527,1.146-1.332,1.715c-0.191,0.136-0.263,0.386-0.172,0.602l0.548,1.306l-2.143,0.9l-0.548-1.306
        c-0.079-0.188-0.262-0.306-0.461-0.306c-0.029,0-0.059,0.002-0.089,0.008c-0.971,0.178-1.443,0.007-2.188-0.26
        c-0.203-0.072-0.429-0.008-0.562,0.162l-0.92,1.17l-1.856-1.41l0.86-1.132c0.132-0.174,0.136-0.413,0.01-0.591
        c-0.432-0.611-0.708-1.271-0.845-2.02c-0.039-0.214-0.212-0.378-0.428-0.406l-1.399-0.18L71.834,27.345z"/>
    <path style="fill:#5E5F5F;" d="M88.478,35.795c-0.653,1.169-0.791,2.077-0.853,3.047l-2.46,0.662
        c-0.396,0.106-0.633,0.512-0.532,0.91l1.303,5.108c0.049,0.193,0.173,0.358,0.345,0.46c0.172,0.101,0.375,0.131,0.569,0.081
        l2.414-0.622c0.599,0.849,1.301,1.564,2.129,2.17l-0.669,2.416c-0.053,0.192-0.028,0.397,0.07,0.57
        c0.098,0.173,0.261,0.3,0.453,0.353l5.068,1.401c0.067,0.019,0.134,0.027,0.2,0.027c0.324,0,0.623-0.212,0.719-0.538l0.732-2.49
        c0.961-0.047,1.875-0.166,3.066-0.808l1.719,1.745c0.139,0.142,0.33,0.222,0.528,0.224c0.227,0.029,0.391-0.076,0.532-0.216
        l3.747-3.69c0.295-0.291,0.299-0.765,0.008-1.061l-1.719-1.745c0.653-1.169,0.791-2.077,0.855-3.053l2.501-0.694
        c0.395-0.109,0.628-0.515,0.525-0.912l-1.323-5.089c-0.05-0.192-0.175-0.357-0.347-0.458c-0.171-0.101-0.376-0.129-0.568-0.079
        l-2.426,0.632c-0.593-0.837-1.298-1.551-2.137-2.163l0.658-2.403c0.053-0.192,0.027-0.397-0.072-0.57
        c-0.099-0.173-0.263-0.299-0.455-0.352l-5.087-1.381c-0.396-0.11-0.805,0.123-0.917,0.518l-0.699,2.449
        c-0.958,0.046-1.871,0.167-3.061,0.807l-1.719-1.746c-0.29-0.294-0.765-0.298-1.061-0.008l-3.748,3.69
        c-0.142,0.139-0.222,0.33-0.224,0.528c-0.001,0.199,0.076,0.391,0.216,0.532L88.478,35.795z M91.033,30.894l1.602,1.626
        c0.246,0.25,0.632,0.294,0.932,0.109c1.337-0.835,2.137-0.863,3.387-0.906c0.325-0.011,0.606-0.23,0.695-0.543l0.646-2.26
        l3.647,0.99l-0.6,2.192c-0.086,0.315,0.041,0.649,0.314,0.827c1.015,0.66,1.815,1.47,2.447,2.477
        c0.174,0.278,0.512,0.412,0.824,0.327l2.217-0.578l0.949,3.648l-2.308,0.641c-0.311,0.086-0.534,0.412-0.551,0.734
        c-0.062,1.208-0.103,2.005-0.957,3.324c-0.191,0.295-0.152,0.684,0.095,0.934l1.601,1.625l-2.678,2.638l-1.602-1.626
        c-0.247-0.25-0.635-0.296-0.932-0.109c-1.332,0.834-2.131,0.863-3.388,0.908c-0.323,0.012-0.602,0.228-0.693,0.538l-0.676,2.298
        l-3.634-1.004l0.611-2.208c0.087-0.315-0.04-0.651-0.314-0.83c-0.997-0.646-1.795-1.459-2.439-2.484
        c-0.173-0.277-0.507-0.41-0.822-0.327l-2.201,0.567l-0.935-3.663l2.27-0.611c0.314-0.084,0.54-0.402,0.556-0.727
        c0.06-1.21,0.1-2.009,0.956-3.333c0.191-0.295,0.151-0.683-0.096-0.934l-1.601-1.625L91.033,30.894z"/>
    <path style="fill:#5E5F5F;" d="M77.405,31.818c0.332,0.135,0.679,0.203,1.026,0.203c0.357,0,0.714-0.071,1.053-0.214
        c0.668-0.281,1.187-0.805,1.461-1.477c0.275-0.672,0.271-1.411-0.01-2.08c-0.581-1.38-2.174-2.033-3.556-1.452
        c-1.38,0.58-2.032,2.176-1.452,3.557C76.209,31.025,76.733,31.544,77.405,31.818z M77.767,27.722
        c0.871-0.367,1.879,0.044,2.247,0.917c0.177,0.422,0.18,0.889,0.006,1.313c-0.173,0.424-0.501,0.756-0.923,0.933
        c-0.423,0.177-0.889,0.18-1.313,0.007c-0.424-0.173-0.755-0.501-0.933-0.924C76.483,29.096,76.894,28.088,77.767,27.722z"/>
    <path style="fill:#5E5F5F;" d="M97.163,44.051c1.079,0,2.159-0.406,2.986-1.222c1.672-1.646,1.692-4.346,0.046-6.019
        c-1.646-1.671-4.347-1.693-6.019-0.046c-1.672,1.646-1.693,4.347-0.046,6.02C94.962,43.628,96.062,44.051,97.163,44.051z
         M95.229,37.833c1.083-1.065,2.832-1.053,3.897,0.03c1.066,1.083,1.053,2.832-0.03,3.898c-1.083,1.066-2.831,1.053-3.898-0.03
        C94.133,40.648,94.146,38.9,95.229,37.833z"/>
    <path style="fill:#5E5F5F;" d="M53.676,46.927c0.157,0,0.315-0.009,0.474-0.027c0,0,0,0,0,0c2.263-0.26,3.893-2.313,3.633-4.576
        s-2.311-3.89-4.576-3.633c-2.263,0.26-3.893,2.313-3.634,4.576C49.816,45.37,51.607,46.927,53.676,46.927z M53.378,40.18
        c0.102-0.012,0.202-0.017,0.302-0.017c1.317,0,2.458,0.991,2.612,2.331c0.166,1.441-0.873,2.749-2.314,2.915
        c-1.439,0.17-2.749-0.874-2.915-2.314C50.899,41.653,51.937,40.346,53.378,40.18z"/>
    <path style="fill:#5E5F5F;" d="M44.511,46.65c0.156,0.124,0.355,0.181,0.552,0.158l1.519-0.174
        c0.367,0.679,0.822,1.295,1.359,1.839l-0.606,1.398c-0.079,0.182-0.083,0.389-0.01,0.574c0.073,0.185,0.217,0.333,0.399,0.413
        l4.136,1.794c0.095,0.042,0.197,0.062,0.298,0.062c0.093,0,0.187-0.018,0.275-0.052c0.185-0.073,0.333-0.217,0.413-0.399l0.607-1.4
        c0.775,0.024,1.53-0.064,2.273-0.261l0.909,1.227c0.118,0.16,0.295,0.266,0.492,0.295c0.195,0.029,0.397-0.021,0.557-0.139
        l3.622-2.685c0.333-0.247,0.402-0.716,0.156-1.049l-0.905-1.221c0.401-0.652,0.705-1.357,0.907-2.104l1.516-0.174
        c0.412-0.047,0.707-0.419,0.66-0.831l-0.515-4.479c-0.047-0.412-0.423-0.704-0.831-0.66l-1.518,0.174
        c-0.366-0.681-0.821-1.297-1.359-1.841l0.606-1.397c0.165-0.38-0.01-0.822-0.39-0.986l-4.136-1.794
        c-0.182-0.079-0.389-0.082-0.574-0.01c-0.185,0.073-0.333,0.217-0.413,0.399l-0.608,1.401c-0.765-0.026-1.528,0.065-2.271,0.261
        l-0.91-1.227c-0.247-0.333-0.716-0.402-1.049-0.156l-3.622,2.685c-0.16,0.119-0.266,0.296-0.295,0.493
        c-0.029,0.197,0.021,0.397,0.14,0.557l0.906,1.221c-0.402,0.652-0.706,1.356-0.909,2.104l-1.515,0.174
        c-0.198,0.022-0.378,0.123-0.502,0.279s-0.18,0.354-0.158,0.552l0.514,4.479C44.254,46.346,44.355,46.527,44.511,46.65z
         M46.587,42.095c0.323-0.037,0.585-0.278,0.65-0.597c0.186-0.925,0.553-1.774,1.09-2.525c0.189-0.265,0.187-0.622-0.008-0.883
        l-0.772-1.041l2.417-1.792l0.777,1.048c0.194,0.262,0.537,0.37,0.842,0.264c0.882-0.298,1.799-0.404,2.726-0.313
        c0.321,0.03,0.631-0.149,0.76-0.448l0.519-1.196l2.76,1.198l-0.517,1.191c-0.129,0.298-0.052,0.646,0.192,0.861
        c0.693,0.612,1.243,1.356,1.633,2.211c0.135,0.296,0.451,0.474,0.768,0.434l1.295-0.149l0.344,2.989l-1.294,0.149
        c-0.324,0.037-0.586,0.279-0.65,0.598c-0.185,0.922-0.551,1.771-1.089,2.524c-0.189,0.265-0.186,0.621,0.008,0.883l0.771,1.041
        l-2.416,1.792l-0.776-1.047c-0.193-0.262-0.533-0.368-0.843-0.264c-0.882,0.297-1.8,0.403-2.728,0.313
        c-0.32-0.031-0.631,0.149-0.76,0.448l-0.519,1.195l-2.76-1.198l0.517-1.191c0.129-0.298,0.052-0.646-0.191-0.86
        c-0.693-0.613-1.243-1.357-1.634-2.211c-0.135-0.295-0.447-0.468-0.768-0.433l-1.296,0.149l-0.343-2.989L46.587,42.095z"/>
    <path style="fill:#5E5F5F;" d="M114.134,49.133c0.086,0,0.174-0.005,0.262-0.015h0c1.253-0.144,2.157-1.281,2.013-2.535
        c-0.144-1.253-1.274-2.159-2.535-2.013c-0.607,0.07-1.151,0.372-1.531,0.851c-0.38,0.479-0.551,1.077-0.481,1.684
        C111.994,48.27,112.987,49.133,114.134,49.133z M113.126,46.042c0.214-0.27,0.521-0.44,0.862-0.479
        c0.05-0.005,0.099-0.008,0.148-0.008c0.645,0,1.204,0.486,1.279,1.142c0.081,0.706-0.428,1.347-1.133,1.428
        c-0.709,0.074-1.347-0.428-1.428-1.134C112.815,46.649,112.911,46.312,113.126,46.042z"/>
    <path style="fill:#5E5F5F;" d="M109.486,43.17c-0.02,0.131,0.014,0.265,0.093,0.371l0.61,0.822c-0.251,0.4-0.441,0.838-0.562,1.294
        l-1.016,0.117c-0.274,0.031-0.471,0.279-0.439,0.554l0.272,2.37c0.015,0.132,0.082,0.252,0.186,0.334
        c0.104,0.082,0.234,0.121,0.368,0.105l1.015-0.116c0.22,0.415,0.502,0.792,0.844,1.127l-0.41,0.944
        c-0.053,0.122-0.055,0.259-0.006,0.383c0.048,0.124,0.144,0.222,0.266,0.275l2.188,0.949c0.064,0.028,0.132,0.041,0.198,0.041
        c0.193,0,0.377-0.112,0.459-0.301l0.41-0.944c0.472,0.021,0.945-0.032,1.4-0.155l0.609,0.821c0.164,0.222,0.476,0.268,0.699,0.104
        l1.917-1.42c0.106-0.079,0.177-0.197,0.197-0.329c0.02-0.131-0.014-0.265-0.093-0.371l-0.61-0.822
        c0.251-0.401,0.442-0.839,0.563-1.294l1.016-0.117c0.274-0.031,0.471-0.279,0.439-0.554l-0.272-2.37
        c-0.031-0.274-0.279-0.475-0.554-0.439l-1.013,0.116c-0.22-0.416-0.503-0.794-0.847-1.13l0.409-0.941
        c0.053-0.122,0.055-0.259,0.006-0.383c-0.048-0.124-0.144-0.222-0.266-0.275l-2.188-0.949c-0.253-0.113-0.548,0.006-0.657,0.259
        l-0.409,0.942c-0.479-0.02-0.948,0.032-1.402,0.156l-0.607-0.82c-0.079-0.106-0.197-0.177-0.328-0.197
        c-0.134-0.018-0.265,0.014-0.372,0.093l-1.917,1.42C109.576,42.921,109.505,43.039,109.486,43.17z M110.529,46.202
        c0.1-0.558,0.333-1.094,0.673-1.55c0.132-0.177,0.133-0.42,0.001-0.597l-0.524-0.707l1.113-0.825l0.522,0.705
        c0.132,0.178,0.365,0.25,0.573,0.172c0.532-0.193,1.096-0.259,1.677-0.187c0.224,0.025,0.43-0.095,0.518-0.297l0.353-0.811
        l1.271,0.551l-0.352,0.811c-0.088,0.203-0.033,0.439,0.137,0.582c0.45,0.378,0.791,0.833,1.013,1.352
        c0.086,0.203,0.286,0.327,0.517,0.3l0.87-0.1l0.158,1.376l-0.873,0.101c-0.219,0.025-0.396,0.191-0.435,0.409
        c-0.099,0.556-0.333,1.092-0.675,1.551c-0.132,0.177-0.132,0.419-0.001,0.597l0.524,0.707l-1.113,0.825l-0.523-0.706
        c-0.132-0.178-0.364-0.248-0.572-0.172c-0.533,0.193-1.098,0.255-1.676,0.186c-0.222-0.025-0.43,0.095-0.518,0.297l-0.354,0.813
        l-1.271-0.551l0.353-0.813c0.088-0.203,0.033-0.439-0.137-0.582c-0.448-0.377-0.789-0.832-1.011-1.351
        c-0.087-0.203-0.296-0.329-0.517-0.299l-0.871,0.1l-0.158-1.376l0.873-0.101C110.313,46.585,110.49,46.419,110.529,46.202z"/>
    <path style="fill:#5E5F5F;" d="M71.742,47.832c0.532,0.423,1.177,0.647,1.846,0.647c0.114,0,0.229-0.007,0.345-0.02
        c1.631-0.187,2.805-1.666,2.618-3.297s-1.663-2.805-3.297-2.618c-0.79,0.09-1.497,0.483-1.992,1.106
        c-0.495,0.623-0.717,1.401-0.626,2.19C70.726,46.63,71.119,47.337,71.742,47.832z M72.045,44.272
        c0.329-0.414,0.798-0.675,1.323-0.735c0.076-0.009,0.152-0.013,0.227-0.013c0.99,0,1.847,0.745,1.962,1.751
        c0.124,1.083-0.656,2.065-1.739,2.189c-0.524,0.06-1.041-0.088-1.455-0.417s-0.675-0.798-0.735-1.322
        C71.569,45.202,71.717,44.686,72.045,44.272z"/>
    <path style="fill:#5E5F5F;" d="M67.346,40.443c-0.02,0.131,0.014,0.265,0.093,0.371l0.923,1.245
        c-0.396,0.604-0.688,1.276-0.858,1.976l-1.539,0.177c-0.274,0.031-0.471,0.279-0.439,0.554l0.376,3.281
        c0.031,0.274,0.278,0.47,0.554,0.439l1.537-0.176c0.323,0.641,0.754,1.218,1.289,1.722l-0.621,1.43
        c-0.053,0.122-0.055,0.259-0.006,0.383c0.048,0.124,0.144,0.222,0.266,0.275l3.031,1.314c0.064,0.028,0.132,0.042,0.198,0.042
        c0.193,0,0.377-0.112,0.459-0.301l0.621-1.43c0.73,0.045,1.445-0.034,2.137-0.237l0.923,1.244c0.163,0.221,0.476,0.268,0.699,0.104
        l2.654-1.967c0.106-0.079,0.177-0.197,0.197-0.329c0.02-0.131-0.014-0.265-0.093-0.371l-0.923-1.245
        c0.397-0.605,0.69-1.277,0.86-1.976l1.539-0.177c0.132-0.015,0.252-0.082,0.334-0.186c0.083-0.104,0.12-0.236,0.105-0.368
        l-0.377-3.281c-0.031-0.274-0.279-0.477-0.554-0.439l-1.533,0.176c-0.323-0.641-0.756-1.219-1.292-1.725l0.619-1.426
        c0.053-0.122,0.055-0.259,0.006-0.383c-0.048-0.124-0.144-0.222-0.266-0.275l-3.03-1.314c-0.253-0.111-0.548,0.006-0.657,0.259
        l-0.62,1.426c-0.728-0.044-1.449,0.035-2.14,0.239l-0.92-1.242c-0.079-0.106-0.197-0.177-0.328-0.197
        c-0.133-0.019-0.265,0.014-0.372,0.093l-2.653,1.967C67.436,40.194,67.366,40.312,67.346,40.443z M69.38,41.753l-0.84-1.133
        l1.85-1.372l0.837,1.13c0.133,0.178,0.367,0.248,0.572,0.172c0.767-0.279,1.577-0.37,2.412-0.269
        c0.22,0.029,0.43-0.095,0.518-0.297l0.564-1.299l2.113,0.916l-0.564,1.299c-0.088,0.203-0.033,0.439,0.136,0.582
        c0.647,0.545,1.137,1.199,1.457,1.945c0.086,0.203,0.297,0.331,0.517,0.3l1.395-0.16l0.263,2.288l-1.399,0.161
        c-0.219,0.025-0.396,0.191-0.435,0.409c-0.145,0.811-0.472,1.561-0.97,2.229c-0.132,0.177-0.132,0.419,0,0.597l0.84,1.133
        l-1.85,1.372l-0.84-1.132c-0.131-0.177-0.363-0.247-0.571-0.172c-0.768,0.277-1.579,0.365-2.409,0.267
        c-0.223-0.026-0.43,0.095-0.518,0.298l-0.565,1.303L69.778,51.4l0.565-1.302c0.088-0.203,0.033-0.439-0.137-0.582
        c-0.644-0.542-1.133-1.195-1.453-1.941c-0.087-0.202-0.29-0.325-0.517-0.299l-1.397,0.16l-0.263-2.287l1.4-0.161
        c0.219-0.025,0.396-0.191,0.435-0.409c0.145-0.813,0.471-1.563,0.968-2.229C69.511,42.173,69.512,41.931,69.38,41.753z"/>
    <path style="fill:#5E5F5F;" d="M63.615,32.92c0.147,0.033,0.296,0.049,0.444,0.049c0.379,0,0.751-0.107,1.079-0.315
        c0.455-0.289,0.771-0.738,0.888-1.264c0.243-1.086-0.444-2.168-1.53-2.411c-1.085-0.247-2.168,0.443-2.411,1.53
        c-0.118,0.526-0.023,1.066,0.266,1.522S63.089,32.803,63.615,32.92z M63.06,30.728c0.106-0.474,0.528-0.797,0.995-0.797
        c0.073,0,0.147,0.008,0.222,0.024c0.548,0.123,0.895,0.668,0.772,1.217c-0.06,0.265-0.219,0.492-0.449,0.638
        c-0.229,0.146-0.501,0.193-0.769,0.135c-0.266-0.06-0.492-0.219-0.638-0.449C63.049,31.266,63.001,30.993,63.06,30.728z"/>
    <path style="fill:#5E5F5F;" d="M59.277,31.433l0.796,0.178c0.062,0.367,0.175,0.723,0.339,1.064l-0.557,0.605
        c-0.09,0.098-0.137,0.227-0.131,0.359c0.005,0.132,0.063,0.257,0.161,0.347l1.492,1.371c0.203,0.188,0.52,0.174,0.707-0.03
        l0.557-0.605c0.353,0.134,0.717,0.217,1.089,0.248l0.245,0.78c0.067,0.213,0.264,0.35,0.477,0.35c0.049,0,0.1-0.007,0.149-0.023
        l1.933-0.606c0.126-0.04,0.232-0.128,0.294-0.246c0.061-0.117,0.073-0.254,0.034-0.381l-0.245-0.781
        c0.29-0.238,0.545-0.516,0.758-0.823l0.798,0.178c0.128,0.029,0.265,0.005,0.377-0.065c0.112-0.071,0.191-0.184,0.22-0.313
        l0.441-1.977c0.061-0.27-0.109-0.537-0.379-0.597l-0.794-0.178c-0.062-0.367-0.176-0.724-0.341-1.067l0.556-0.604
        c0.09-0.098,0.137-0.227,0.131-0.359c-0.005-0.132-0.063-0.257-0.161-0.347l-1.492-1.371c-0.203-0.186-0.519-0.174-0.707,0.03
        l-0.556,0.604c-0.354-0.135-0.719-0.218-1.091-0.248l-0.244-0.778c-0.083-0.263-0.363-0.411-0.626-0.328l-1.934,0.605
        c-0.126,0.04-0.232,0.128-0.293,0.246c-0.062,0.117-0.074,0.254-0.034,0.381l0.245,0.781c-0.289,0.238-0.544,0.517-0.757,0.823
        l-0.798-0.178c-0.266-0.058-0.537,0.109-0.597,0.379l-0.442,1.977c-0.029,0.129-0.005,0.265,0.065,0.377
        C59.035,31.325,59.148,31.404,59.277,31.433z M60.207,29.565l0.655,0.146c0.216,0.05,0.437-0.051,0.545-0.244
        c0.232-0.415,0.551-0.762,0.948-1.031c0.183-0.124,0.262-0.353,0.196-0.563l-0.201-0.641l0.979-0.307l0.2,0.639
        c0.066,0.211,0.284,0.386,0.484,0.351c0.475,0.002,0.928,0.098,1.364,0.31c0.199,0.096,0.437,0.051,0.587-0.111l0.458-0.497
        l0.755,0.694l-0.458,0.497c-0.149,0.163-0.174,0.404-0.062,0.594c0.25,0.42,0.394,0.869,0.426,1.334
        c0.015,0.22,0.174,0.405,0.39,0.453l0.652,0.146l-0.224,1.001l-0.655-0.146c-0.215-0.05-0.437,0.051-0.545,0.243
        c-0.233,0.415-0.553,0.762-0.95,1.031c-0.183,0.124-0.263,0.353-0.197,0.563l0.201,0.641l-0.979,0.307l-0.201-0.641
        c-0.065-0.208-0.259-0.35-0.477-0.35c-0.002,0-0.004,0-0.006,0c-0.495,0.007-0.929-0.099-1.363-0.311
        c-0.2-0.095-0.438-0.051-0.587,0.111l-0.459,0.499l-0.755-0.694l0.459-0.499c0.149-0.163,0.174-0.404,0.062-0.594
        c-0.249-0.418-0.392-0.867-0.425-1.333c-0.016-0.22-0.174-0.404-0.39-0.452l-0.653-0.146L60.207,29.565z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

I can see the .svg so I know it can't be a major problem, maybe just a syntax error or I forgot to add an asset or something. 
(I attached a .png version of the image so you can see it if that helps at all)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found a web site called [Glyphter](https://glyphter.com/) which accepted the .svg file I created from your .png image. I changed nothing in the image, but inadvertently assigned it to the letter B.

The conversion of the site generated a .ttf and a .woff file which appear to meet your objective.

The image below is the windows result of a double click on the .ttf file.

[image: gearhead image]

The site request that one join, but allows for a download without signing in.